# DBUnit Test Comparison Failure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dbunit

I have a problem with a db unit test which tests if data is persisted correctly. Therefore I created an sample db with my data and tried to compare the setup and the expected data. The id generation and everything else should be managed by hibernate

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseTearDown("empty.xml")
public class UserDaoTests {

    @Autowired
    UserAdminDao userDao;

    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("db-setup.xml")
    @ExpectedDatabase("db-expected.xml")
    public void testPersistUser(){

        User user = new User();

        user.setUserId("user2");
        user.setName("test2");
        user.setEmail("user2@email.com");
        user.setLocked(false);
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setVersion(0);
        user.setPassword("asdfasdf");

        userDao.persist(user);

    }

}
```

And my setups are:

```
<dataset>       
    <user id="1" userId="user1" name="test1" email="user1@email.com" locked="0" enabled="1" version="0" password="asdfasdf" /> 

</dataset>
```

and the same with user id=2 underneath:

```
<user id="2" userId="user2" name="test2" email="user2@email.com" locked="0" enabled="1" version="0" password="asdfasdf" />
```

But I'm getting an Comparison error:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: row count (table=user) expected:<[2]> but was:<[1]>
```

Not sure where my mistake is. thx for any help :)

Comment: but as I understand it `@DatabaseSetup` means the the db status before the test and `@ExpectedDatabase` means after the test. Why can't there be a user in the db befor the test. After I persist another (user2) there should be 2, or am I getting something wrong ?

Comment: Did you already verify that your persist method works outside your test? If it doesn't the ComparisonFailure sounds logic...

Comment: There seems to be a problem with my `@Transactional` DAO method and dbunit. I added `TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class`, but I think that `@ExpectedDatabase` is called after the Transaction.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but with delete:
`junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: row count (table=user) expected:<[4]> but was:<[5]>`
I've used a postgres db, and I see the row is no longer there... Did you made it work?

Comment: A few years later... any update?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add table name to "@ExpectedDatabase"
Something like this
@ExpectedDatabase(value = "dataset.xml", table = "your_table_name")

Comment: Thanks. I come from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730837/junit-framework-comparisonfailure-table-count-expected-1-but-was-95 your comment helped me!

Comment: There is a NON_STRICT_UNORDERED mode to avoid explicit table name:
https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/pull/48