# junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: table count expected [1] but was [95]

Tags: java, spring, junit, dbunit

I'm new to spring and dbunit and have problem with testing my dao layer. The entry is inserted succsessfully, but test ends with failure. Could you help me, please?

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener;


import com.epam.lab.marharytakhramtsova.javalab.task1.dao.TagDAO;
import com.epam.lab.marharytakhramtsova.javalab.task1.dto.Tag;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.annotation.DatabaseSetup;
import com.github.springtestdbunit.annotation.ExpectedDatabase;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring-config.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
public class TestTagDAO {

    @Autowired
    private TagDAO tagDAO;

    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup(value = "/TagDAOTest.xml")
    @ExpectedDatabase(value= "/expectedData.xml")
    public void testInsert() throws Exception {
        Tag tagToInsert = new Tag(4, "insertedTag");
        tagDAO.insert(tagToInsert);
    }

}
```

TagDAOTest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>   
    <tag tag_id = "3" tag_name="myTag3" />
</dataset>
```

expectedData.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset> 
  <tag tag_id = "3" tag_name="myTag3" />
  <tag tag_id = "4" tag_name="insertedTag" />
 </dataset>
```

Here is failure trace

[image]

I would be very grateful for the help!

Comment: Looks like you have already many recrds in your database

Comment: My table in db is just the same as expected file

Comment: I do not think so. DBUnit says you have would like to insert 1 record, so there should be one record in the table. But there are 95 records in the table

Comment: I think it is not count of records in the table, but it is count of some tables in my db (but I don't know what kind of tables they are). Because when I drop one of my tables now the count became 94, but not 95.

Comment: Then maybe it is the numbers of tables in your db that not matches.

Comment: But then I can't understand this:

SQL> SELECT count(table_name) FROM all_tables;

COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
-----------------
               79

Comment: Did you consider [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com) instead of `DbUnit`? But anyway: you can solve your problem by connecting to your database directly and checking its state manually. Also printing SQL statements generated by your DAO can be helpful.

Comment: please refer this answer for more details.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909399/dbunit-test-comparison-failure/38392016#38392016

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup(value = "/TagDAOTest.xml")
@ExpectedDatabase(assertionMode=DatabaseAssertionMode.NON_STRICT, value= "/expectedData.xml")
public void testInsert() throws Exception {
    Tag tagToInsert = new Tag(4, "insertedTag");
    tagDAO.insert(tagToInsert);
}
```